# For loops suddenly stop (javascript)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i] === args[j]) {
        delete arr[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return arr.filter(Boolean);
}
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3))
```

If I console.log it'll just appear [1, 1, 2, 3], I have tried with the different argument but it still points to the problem that the second for loop suddenly stops after deleting the first number.

Can somebody explain why is that to me? Many thanks

Comment: You are using wrong indexes while comparing. Use `i` is for `args` and `j` for `arr`

Comment: Also, note that `args[0]` is the `arr`. So,  you can start the loop at `var i = 1`

Comment: `arr.filter(Boolean)` removes `0` from the array since it is falsy.